# Strange "attempt to access beyond end of device", where to look?

Tags: xen, ext4

I am running a few Xen servers on my company network. Recently, on one of them, I have been trying to rsync (on the Dom0 console) a big server image from another machine, but every time run in to a system crash after somewhere between 30 and 100 GB. The syslog and kernel log show me something like this:

```
Sep 12 16:41:19 ampxen1 kernel: [ 1730.917516] attempt to access beyond end of device
Sep 12 16:41:19 ampxen1 kernel: [ 1730.917518] dm-1: rw=1, want=8878402463988083936, limit=3759505408
Sep 12 16:41:19 ampxen1 kernel: [ 1730.917520] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 33030164 (offset 47354740736 size 5881856 starting block 1109800307998510491)
```

...continuing with several hundred thousands of similar lines per second, eventually making the machine unreachable. The very high number of the starting block of the EXT4-write operation (that's 10^18 or the exabyte range) is clearly what to look at, but I am unable to find any mention of what could be the cause.

The server is based on ubuntu-18.04.03, standard xen install from the repositories. Storage is two 2TB disks in RAID1, configured as seen below, EXT4 filesystem on the large partition used for our server images. I have checked the disks with smartctl and the file system(s) with e2fsck, for what it's worth. It seems to be a file system issue, but I am wondering whether the xen kernel could be involved. Any ideas of what to look for would be appreciated!

```
$ lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                          7:0    0  500G  0 loop  
sda                            8:0    0  1,8T  0 disk  
├─sda1                         8:1    0  476M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0  1,8T  0 part  
│ └─md0                        9:0    0  1,8T  0 raid1 
│   ├─ampxen1.0-ampxen1.dom0 253:0    0 23,3G  0 lvm   /
│   └─ampxen1.0-ampxen1.vms0 253:1    0  1,8T  0 lvm   /srv/vms0
└─sda3                         8:3    0 46,5G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb                            8:16   0  1,8T  0 disk  
├─sdb1                         8:17   0  476M  0 part  
├─sdb2                         8:18   0  1,8T  0 part  
│ └─md0                        9:0    0  1,8T  0 raid1 
│   ├─ampxen1.0-ampxen1.dom0 253:0    0 23,3G  0 lvm   /
│   └─ampxen1.0-ampxen1.vms0 253:1    0  1,8T  0 lvm   /srv/vms0
└─sdb3                         8:19   0 46,5G  0 part  [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out that the problem was something as trivial as a faulty RAM block – running a memtest showed lots of errors on one of the four 16GB blocks. It seems that memory was only maxed out exactly when copying large files, while my existing virtual servers on the machine were running just fine at all other times.